# Screen Options Wordpress WYSIWYG

Tags: functions, admin, screen-options

Is there any way to set a checkbox for WYSIWYG box in this options so admin is able to hide it in case there's no need for content in a page

Answer (score 0):

The content box is in a `<div>` with an ID of `#postdivrich` so you can hide it using CSS.

Probably the easiest thing to do is to add a settings option to an existing page so you can turn it off or on. The post below covers that in detail:

http://wpengineer.com/2139/adding-settings-to-an-existing-page-using-the-settings-api/

After you have the setting in place, you need to check for it and output CSS in the right place. Add this to `functions.php`:

```
if (get_option('paradise_hide_editor') == 'yes') {
    function paradise_hide_editor() {
        echo '
        <style type="text/css">
        #postdivrich {display: none}
        </style>';
    }
    add_action('admin_head', 'paradise_hide_editor');
}
```